# 777 permission folder is permission denied

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, file-permissions, pgadmin

I'm trying to set up a pgadmin4 server mode panel and it needs access to the directory `var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions`, this folder has 777 permission and the owner is apache (parent folders too). Yet it still gives me this error when I try to open the pgadmin panel

`[Mon Jun 03 08:45:24.203448 2019] [:error] [pid 15544] [remote 141.101.76.223:84] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'`

I accidentally made apache the owner of every file on my server and it still does not work

(I am aware that's a huge security issue but I'm working on it)

Comment: considering its centos - maybe its due to selinux? Might want to *temporarily* disable it to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

Run these below commands for grant additional permission by SELinux:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "/var/log/pgadmin4/"
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "/var/lib/pgadmin4/"
```

---

Another solution:

Disable SELinux for solve this permission issue. Edit `/etc/selinux/config` file:

Change

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

and restart your computer. You can check the currect status of SELinux with `getenforce` command.